# Can QT and FreeRTOS work together on MCU?

Tags: qt, freertos, nxp-microcontroller

I may ask a stupid question. I want to use `FreeRTOS` as the OS on my NXP MCU `MIMXRT1062XXXXB`. The MCU connects to a display. I want to use `QT` to development user interface application. I want to know if it is possible to run QT application base on FreeRTOS on MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible - lots of people do it.  My first Google search for this hit this page on the QT website: https://doc.qt.io/QtForMCUs-2.1/qtul-using-with-freertos.html